# how to install II7 in vista

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-vista

Hi Im trying to setup an environment for my pc , 
Im trying to learn asp.net , and i dont know how setup this in vista , in php its so easy in wamp, but I dont know here, please help me..thanks

any help is appreciated

Comment: If you have Visual Studio 2005 or above you can use it as well without installing IIS, it has "built in" web server.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step by step tutorial on `Microsoft IIS` site :

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/28/installing-iis-7-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

You can install IIS by typing **optionalfeatures.exe** in the Windows Vista Start menu. You don’t however need to install IIS to learn ASP.NET as you desire. A better starting point might be to install Visual Studio Express as that gives you all the tools you need to build your first ASP.NET project. You can download it here:

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to install an all-in-once [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/). It contains the editor with syntax highlighting and intellisense, lightweight IIS server (IIS Express) and a lot of built-in capabilities to jump start learning ASP.NET. You can easily install open source applications like DotNetNuke and start digging into them within minutes.